NextJs: client-side navigation does not work in static build
When I build a nextJs static website, client-side navigation does not work (every link leads to a full page refresh). Why? How can I fix this?
To reproduce, run with the default parameters:
$ npx create-next-app@latest

Go to the created folder, change the next.config.mjs into:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  trailingSlash: true,
};

export default nextConfig;

Create a page src/app/test/page.tsx:
export default function Page() {
  return <p>Hello</p>
}

and add to src/app/page.tsx:
import Link from 'next/link';

…
        <Link href="test">My test link</Link>

run
$ npm run build
$ npx http-serve -c-1 out

EDIT might be related to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/64882

Not sure what version you're using but followed your specs exactly and I don't have an issue in Chrome Version 129.0.6668.90.
reproduced with
setup:
npx create-next-app@latest

using settings of:

✔ What is your project named? … my-app
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use src/ directory? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias (@/*)? … No / Yes

replaced next.config.mjs with:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export",
  trailingSlash: true,
};

export default nextConfig;

app/page.tsx:
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Home() {
  return <Link href="test">My test link</Link>;
}


built with:
npm run build && npx http-serve -c-1 out

produces:
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    6.98 kB        94.2 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          873 B          88.1 kB
└ ○ /test                                138 B          87.4 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            87.2 kB
  ├ chunks/117-f904bb7a2adea4f6.js       31.7 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-aa94ea5c2eabf904.js  53.6 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)          1.86 kB


○  (Static)  prerendered as static content

and:
Starting up http-serve for out
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://10.0.0.11:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server

maybe it's a version issue and since it's not called out here is what I'm using:
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.2.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.15"
  }

could try removing your node_modules and package-lock.json then running a npm i.

Oh really? Weird, I tried with your package file, still same issue. Can you also see the same issue with this MWE I made https://github.com/tobiasBora/mwe-static-link-fail-nextjs/tree/main? For maximum reproducibility, I created a nix file, to test just run nix --experimental-features 'nix-command flakes' build .#mwe && ./result/bin/mwe and you should observe the bug.
